# Can we use font awesome 3.2 with twitter bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am primarily a java developer but in the current project I will be doing the UI part also and I am thinking of using **twitter bootstrap 3.0** version. I know for icons it comes with **glyphyicons** but today I came to know about something called **font awesome 3.2** as well for icons which is considered to be better than the glyphyicons. However I noticed that font awesome 3.2 has been designed and is widely used with previous version of **twitter bootstrap 2.3.2**.

Does anyone know if **twitter bootstrap 3.0** will also support the **font awesome 3.2**? If so, what will have to do if anything apart from including the css files correctly?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you at least attempted using it? It's very easy to get working...

Comment: Your first reference should be the Font Awesome website: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1189

Comment: thanks I am going through all this documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is preventing you from integrating Font Awesome, just follow the documentation:

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Hint - Add this to your `<head>`:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hey but you have mentioned bootstrap 2.3.2 version and I wanna include bootstrap 3.0 version and that was my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having a problem with font awesome 4.0.3 and twitter bootstrap 3.0.2.
Sometimes they work and sometimes not.

There seems to be an "Issue" on github about it at

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/940